# How do I group pivot columns?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table in SQL Server with the following entries.

```
Name    Type        Amount
------------------------------
ABC     Opening     100 
CBD     Invoice     200 
ABC     Spreadsheet 250 
FBD     Closing     400
```

I am trying to create a pivot table based on the above however, I'm also trying to divide the Type column into 3 different columns.

- Opening
- Closing
- Activity(Other)

See table below. Is this possible?

```
Name    Opening  Activity   Closing
----------------------------------------
ABC     100          200          0
CBD       0          250          0
FBD       0            0        400
```

Code so far

```
select *
from
    (
        select  [Name]
                ,[Type]
                ,[Amount]
        from my_Table
    ) a
    pivot(sum(Amount)
    for Type in (Opening], [Closing])
    )as pvt
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this with an aggregate function CASE expression:

```
select 
  name,
  sum(case when type = 'Opening' then Amount else 0 end) Opening,
  sum(case when type not in ('Opening', 'Closing') then Amount else 0 end) Activity,
  sum(case when type = 'Closing' then Amount else 0 end) Closing
from my_table
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef8b9/1). You'd use the CASE logic to look specifically for the `Opening` and `Closing` values, and then the final column would sum the rows where the `Type` is not `Opening` or `Closing`.

You could use PIVOT to get the result, you'll just need to associate the "other" activities before you apply the pivot function.  You can do this using a subquery:

```
select name, Opening, Activity, Closing
from
(
  select 
    name,
    type = case 
              when type not in ('Opening', 'Closing') 
              then 'Activity'
              else type
            end,
    amount
  from my_table
) d
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for type in (Opening, Activity, Closing)
)piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef8b9/2)